# MYSQL query to retrieve friendships only works one way?

Tags: mysql, sql, union, relationship

I have a query that *should* be retrieving a user's friends.

Given the situation that we are `user two` and we `sent` the request to `user one` the query should return the account information for `user one`. ([SQLfiddle of this scenario](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2b74/2/0)) [Works correctly]

Given the situation that we are `user one` and we `recieved` the request from `user two` the query should return the account information for `user two`. ([SQLfiddle of this scenario](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2b74/5/0)) [Returning empty result]

So the query works fine as long as we are the user that sent the request, however if we are the user that received the request it doesn't work.

I can fix this by switching the JOINs, `LEFT => RIGHT`, `RIGHT => LEFT`. But that breaks the first scenario.
I can fix both my doing a union of the two queries. ([SQLfiddle of this scenario](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2b74/4/0)) but surely that's not the most efficent way to do this. So, Basic question: how should I create this query?

SCENARIO ONE:

```
SELECT `accounts`.*,
  IFNULL(`f1`.`sender`,        `f2`.`sender`)        AS `sender`,
  IFNULL(`f1`.`recipient`,     `f2`.`recipient`)     AS `recipient`,
  IFNULL(`f1`.`date_sent`,     `f2`.`date_sent`)     AS `date_sent`,
  IFNULL(`f1`.`date_reviewed`, `f2`.`date_reviewed`) AS `date_reviewed`,
  IFNULL(`f1`.`accepted`,      `f2`.`accepted`)      AS `accepted` 
FROM `accounts` 
  LEFT  JOIN `friendships` AS `f1` ON `accounts`.`id` = `f1`.`sender` 
  RIGHT JOIN `friendships` AS `f2` ON `accounts`.`id` = `f2`.`recipient` 
WHERE (`f1`.`recipient` = 2 OR `f2`.`sender` = 2);
```

PATCHED SCENARIO TWO

```
SELECT `accounts`.*,
  IFNULL(`f1`.`sender`,        `f2`.`sender`)        AS `sender`,
  IFNULL(`f1`.`recipient`,     `f2`.`recipient`)     AS `recipient`,
  IFNULL(`f1`.`date_sent`,     `f2`.`date_sent`)     AS `date_sent`,
  IFNULL(`f1`.`date_reviewed`, `f2`.`date_reviewed`) AS `date_reviewed`,
  IFNULL(`f1`.`accepted`,      `f2`.`accepted`)      AS `accepted` 
FROM `accounts` 
  RIGHT JOIN `friendships` AS `f1` ON `accounts`.`id` = `f1`.`sender` 
  LEFT  JOIN `friendships` AS `f2` ON `accounts`.`id` = `f2`.`recipient` 
WHERE (`f1`.`recipient` = 2 OR `f2`.`sender` = 2);
```

WORKING FOR BOTH SCENARIOS (Question is basically; how can I do this without a union?):

```
SELECT `accounts`.*,
  IFNULL(`f1`.`sender`,        `f2`.`sender`)        AS `sender`,
  IFNULL(`f1`.`recipient`,     `f2`.`recipient`)     AS `recipient`,
  IFNULL(`f1`.`date_sent`,     `f2`.`date_sent`)     AS `date_sent`,
  IFNULL(`f1`.`date_reviewed`, `f2`.`date_reviewed`) AS `date_reviewed`,
  IFNULL(`f1`.`accepted`,      `f2`.`accepted`)      AS `accepted` 
FROM `accounts` 
  LEFT  JOIN `friendships` AS `f1` ON `accounts`.`id` = `f1`.`sender` 
  RIGHT JOIN `friendships` AS `f2` ON `accounts`.`id` = `f2`.`recipient` 
WHERE (`f1`.`recipient` = 1 OR `f2`.`sender` = 1)
UNION
SELECT `accounts`.*,
  IFNULL(`f1`.`sender`,        `f2`.`sender`)        AS `sender`,
  IFNULL(`f1`.`recipient`,     `f2`.`recipient`)     AS `recipient`,
  IFNULL(`f1`.`date_sent`,     `f2`.`date_sent`)     AS `date_sent`,
  IFNULL(`f1`.`date_reviewed`, `f2`.`date_reviewed`) AS `date_reviewed`,
  IFNULL(`f1`.`accepted`,      `f2`.`accepted`)      AS `accepted` 
FROM `accounts` 
  RIGHT  JOIN `friendships` AS `f1` ON `accounts`.`id` = `f1`.`sender` 
  LEFT JOIN `friendships` AS `f2` ON `accounts`.`id` = `f2`.`recipient` 
WHERE (`f1`.`recipient` = 1 OR `f2`.`sender` = 1);
```

SCHEMA CREATION:

```
CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `type` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*Data for the table `accounts` */

insert  into `accounts`
(`id`,`status`,`type`,`username`,`first_name`,`last_name`) 
values 
(1,1,'writer','user1','User','One'),
(2,1,'writer','user2','User','Two'),
(3,1,'publisher','user3','User','Three');

CREATE TABLE `friendships` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sender` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `recipient` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_sent` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_reviewed` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `accepted` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*Data for the table `friendships` */

insert  into `friendships`
(`id`,`sender`,`recipient`,`date_sent`,`date_reviewed`,`accepted`) 
values (3,2,1,'2013-07-16 20:54:46',NULL,NULL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this [query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2b74/31). I removed two joins. And only one join is needed, both side will work.

```
SELECT `accounts`.*, `f1`.`sender`  AS `sender`,`f1`.`recipient`  AS `recipient`,`f1`.`date_sent`  AS `date_sent`,  `f1`.`date_reviewed` AS `date_reviewed`,`f1`.`accepted`    AS `accepted` FROM `accounts`   JOIN `friendships` AS `f1` ON (`accounts`.`id` = `f1`.`sender`   or `accounts`.`id` = `f1`.`recipient`) WHERE    if(`f1`.`recipient` = 1, `f1`.`sender` , if(`f1`.`sender` = 1, `f1`.`recipient` , 0)) = `accounts`.`id`;
```

Comment: Thank you; I ended up with something very similar, Just before I accept this are you able to explain why you did the where with the if's as opposed to just http://pastie.org/8145449

Comment: Actually i didn't think much about this,i simply wrote it that's it. Any way your code also nice.